# OSX NSFont differs from the exact same font in Photoshop

Tags: macos, photoshop, nsfont

I've set my font in Photoshop to be Helvetica Neue Regular with 22pt - without any additional customizations.

Now I need the exact same result in my OSX application which seems to be quite hard to achieve.

I modify the font of my NSTextField using

```
self.label.font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:22];
```

I've created a comparison of HelveticaNeue(regular) and HelveticaNeue-Medium, Photoshop and OSX.
It seems like the OSX part is always a bit more bold and has a slightly reduced letter spacing.

It might be possible to play around a while and adjust the font on OSX using NSAttribuedString until it matches to Photoshop font, but is this really necessary? Shouldn't the font be exactly the same?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to render fonts. Apparently, Photoshop has its own font-rendering engine and it differs from what `NSTextField` is doing by default.

If you zoom your image up in size (in a way that doesn't attempt to smooth the result), you'll see that the Photoshop rendering uses gray-scale anti-aliasing while the OS X rendering uses sub-pixel anti-aliasing. The OS X rendering has color fringes. When rendered at normal sizes, those colors end up lighting the different RGB elements in the LCD screen. Rather than looking colored, it just looks like changing in brightness. Basically, sub-pixel anti-aliasing uses the layout of the color elements within LCD pixels to increase the resolution at which it can render.

I also suspect that the OS X rendering engine is using sub-pixel glyph positioning. That allows for the sizing and spacing of glyphs to more closely follow what the font prescribes, making smaller compromises when being rendered to a grid of pixels. For example, look at the first line (Helvetica Neue 22pt: Photoshop). The spacing between the "H" and the "e" and between the "l" and the "v" looks wrong to me. OS X looks better to my eye.

If you render text yourself, you can turn off sub-pixel anti-aliasing using `CGContextSetShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts()` and turn off sub-pixel positioning using `CGContextSetShouldSubpixelPositionFonts()`. (The documentation suggests that turning off sub-pixel positioning also turns off sub-pixel anti-aliasing, although I'm not sure why that would necessarily follow.) See if that produces results more like what Photoshop is giving you.

By the way, it's probably possible to adjust how Photoshop renders the font, too. Just because two things are ostensibly rendering the same font, doesn't mean they will produce identical pixels.